# Add a version in app store to support previous versions of iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, version, organizer

I have uploaded an app in app store that supports iOS7 and above. Now I would like to add a version to the same that supports iOS 5 and above but during validation and submission it shows some issues that it needs version higher than the previous. I don't get it Please help me out. please find below the image of the issues that i faced.![image]

Comment: they are talking about the version of your app, not of the available iOS allowed. You need to set a higher number for your app number version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a higher version in `info.plist`. see the screenshot.

[image]

You can also change it from here..

[image]

In your case the version number may be 1.1. Hope this helps. :)

**EDIT**

Go to info.plist form supporting Files from your project. Then make sure `Bundle versions string, short` and `Bundle version` is set to 1.1.

[image]

Comment: I've changed the bundle version but it still shows an error with the bundle version mismatch and should be higher than the previous version.

Comment: What is the version number of your app that you want to upload in itunes?

Comment: version number is 1.1 and that is not the problem now. The CFBundle version is the one causing the problem

Comment: can you post the new errors or the errors are same?

Comment: I have tried 1.1 and 1.2, still i get the same error

Comment: the previous version is 1.0

Comment: Did you create a new version in iTunedConnect? What is that version number?

Comment: the newly created version number is 1.1. It had asked me only for app version number and i had given it as 1.1. Nothing about the CFBundle version

Comment: Then you should give 1.1 as version number. I've point out all the places from where you can change version number. Do it. Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project?

Answer (score 1):

try to change version your app in *-Info.plist

Comment: Ive changed the app version but still it shows the same error.

Comment: I'm finding difficulties in changing the CFBundleVersion number

Comment: What difficulties ? Not save? If yes, then save your project, close xcode and open with text editor your *-Info.plist file, change <CFBundleVersion>, after open your project and check <CFBundleVersion>

Comment: how do i find out the bundle version in my ituneConnect account.

Comment: you can find in iTunesConnect -> "Manage Your Apps" -> YOUR APP -> "View details" -> "Binary Details" there you can find "Bundle Version"